# How to close a file in the main function in python?

Tags: python, file-io

I am writing a function that helps in opening a user-supplied file. Here is what I have so far:

```
def main():

    open_file()


def open_file():
    input_file_name = str(input("Input file name: "))
    while input_file_name != 'measles.txt':
        input_file_name = str(input("Please enter a valid input file name: "))
    f1 = open(input_file_name, 'r')
    return f1

main()
```

**My question is:** once I call `open_file` in `main`, how do I close the file that I opened in the `open_file` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you return the file object from `open_file()`, you can (have to) pick it up somehow. YOu do so by using the function call as (a part of) an expression.

So either do

```
f = open_file()
```

and do whatever you need, or do

```
open_file().close()
```

being a shorthand of

```
f = open_file()
f.close()
```

(both of them being quite pointless)

or, which seems the most appropriate thing to do,

```
with open_file() as f:
    do_whatever(f)
```

being a shorthand of

```
f = open_file()
with f:
    do_whatever(f)
```

which closes the file automatically.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use the [`with` statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm):

```
def main():
    with open_file() as f:
        # use f here
```

The file will automatically be closed when the code exists from the `with` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a variable that references the file object, and use that to close the file manually later on:

```
def main():
    f = open_file()
    # Operate on file ...
    f.close()
```